# (OMNeT++) Why PacketQueue is always 0?

Tags: queue, router, omnet++, packet, inet

I'm trying to code in OMNeT++ an app that gets the queue length from the node where it is invoked and sends it to another node.

The plan is to modify the UdpBasicApp.cc file invoked in a router and make it get the length of the queue of the DropTailQueue module.

Searching online I found that this is the right method...

```
cModule *mod = getModuleByPath("router3.eth[*].mac.queue");                  
queueing::PacketQueue *queue = check_and_cast<queueing::PacketQueue*>(mod);
int c = queue->getNumPackets();
EV << c;
```

...since the DropTailQueue extends the PacketQueue module.
I put a print at the end to see if there was something wrong.
When I run the simulation, using the modified UdpBasicApp module, c is always 0.
I hardly doubt that the queue is always 0, but I don't know how to verify this doubt.
If it's an error, why is it always 0?

Comment: When do you check the size of the queue?

Comment: In the .ini file I set the sendInterval parameter to 2 seconds (2s). I put the code showed in the question in the sendPacket() function of the UdpBasicApp.cc file, before everything else, so everytime a packet is to be sent by the UdpBasicApp the value of int c is updated. Now that I think about it, I'm not sure if I have to delete the pointers and the int at the end of the sendPacket() function

Comment: However this is only a preliminary stage to see how it works. The next step is to create a message where I invoke the getNumPackets() using the code above, and then modify the sendPackets() function in the UdpBasicApp.cc file to send the newly created message.

Comment: A moment ago I added this line of code:

int d = queue->getMaxNumPackets();
EV << d

and the simulation shows the right number that I set as max queue capacity. So I don't know why I don't get the right value for the queue length moment by moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is, that you are querying a different queue than you assume. You should not use patterns (i.e. `*`) in your model path, because that may match on multiple `eth` modules, and it's unspecified, which one will be returned.