# (OMNeT++) Where do packets go?

Tags: c++, queue, router, omnet++, inet

I'm trying to do a project described also here: [PacketQueue is 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65874996/omnet-why-packetqueue-is-always-0?noredirect=1#comment116472114_65874996)

I've modified the UdpBasicApp.cc to suit my needs, and in the handleMessage() function I added a piece of code to retrieve the length of the ethernet queue of a router. However the value returned is always 0.

My .ned file regarding the queue of routers is this:

```
**.router*.eth[*].mac.queue.typename = "DropTailQueue"
**.router*.eth[*].mac.queue.packetCapacity = 51
```

The code added in the UdpBasicApp.cc file is this:

```
cModule *mod = getModuleByPath("router3.eth[*].mac.queue.");                 
queueing::PacketQueue *queue = check_and_cast<queueing::PacketQueue*>(mod);  
int c = queue->getNumPackets();
```

So my question is this: is this the right way to create a queue in a router linked to other nodes with an ethernet link?
My doubt is that maybe packets don't pass through the specified interface, i.e. I've set the ini parameters for the wrong queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not **creating** that queue. It was already instantiated by the OMNeT++ kernel. You are just getting a reference to an already existing module with the `getModuleByPath()` call.

The `router3.eth[*].mac.queue.` module path is rather suspicious in that call. It is hard-coded in all of your application to get the queue length from `router3` even if the app is installed in `router1`. i.e. you are trying to look at the queue length in a completely different node. Then, the `eth[*]` is wrong. As a router obviously contains more than one ethernet interface (otherwise it would not be a router), you must explicitly specify **which** interface you want to sepcify. You must not specify *patterns* in module path (i.e. `eth[0]` or something like that, with an exact index must be specified). And at this point, you have to answer the question which ethernet interface I'm interested in, and specify that index. Finally the `.` end the end is also invalid, so I believe, your code never executes, otherwise the `check_and_cast` part would have raised an error already.

If you wanted to reach the first enthern interface from an UDP app in the **same** node, you would use relative path, something like this: `^.eth[0].mac.queue`

Finally, if you are unsure whether your model works correctly, why not start the model with Qtenv, and check whether the given module receives any packet? Like,, drill down in the model until the given queue is opened as a simple module (i.e. you see the empty inside of the queue module) and then tap the *run/fast run until next event in this module*. If the simulation does not stop, then that module indeed did not received any packets and your configuration is wrong.

Comment: I edited the code, it makes more sense, but I still got 0. So I analized the simulation in the Qtenv environment and I saw that packets that arrive to the desired ethernet interface are immediately pushed into the queue and popped out of it. I guess there's nothing wrong, the queue is indeed always.
To create saturation in the buffer of the router should I increase the data I'm sending to the router and/or decrease the datarate of the channels? Or are there other settings better suited to do so?

Comment: Indeed, you have to increase the application throughout compared to the limit capacity. There is no other way to fill the queues.

Comment: Hey, I edited the value of the parameters in the .ini file, but now, after 50 seconds I get this message:
"Returning an incomplete chunk is not allowed according to the flags: 1 -- in module (inet::TcpGenericServerApp) Network.server.app[1] ..."

I guess I should lower the amount of data sent, but if I do that I can't create a saturation in the buffer.